# knife backup to migrate from chef11 to chef12

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to migrate a chef server on V11 to a new box running chef server on V12.

I used `knife backup export -D chefbackup`to backup the chefserverv11 to the checkbackup directory

I then used `knife backup restore chefbackup` to restore the backup to the new box running chefserverv12.

During the restore process, i saw the following

```
  === Restoring users ===
ERROR: Failed to create user[admin]: #<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x00000003858a38>; skipping
ERROR: Failed to create user[user1]: #<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x0000000386cd30>; skipping
ERROR: Failed to create user[user2]: #<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x00000003881078>; skipping
=== Restoring nodes ===
Restoring nodes from ../chefbackup/nodes/node1.example.com.json
=== Restoring roles ===
Restoring roles from ../chefbackup/roles/role1.json
Restoring roles from ../chefbackup/roles/role2.json
Restoring roles from ../chefbackup/roles/role3.json
```

Any idea why i the users are failing to get migrated to the new chef server?

Also when i do a `knife node show node1.example.com` i see the following

```
Node Name:   node1.example.com
Environment: _default
FQDN:
IP:
Run List:    role[role1]
Roles:
Recipes:
Platform:
Tags:
```

The FQDN and IP details seem to be missing from the export? The missing details is also causing the following to fail

`knife ssh "name:node1*" "chef-client" -x root -P secretpass`

`FATAL: 1 node found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute`
Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs between Chef Server 11 and 12 changed for some things. You need to use https://github.com/chef/knife-ec-backup for restoring a 12 server. For the upgrade you would generally copy the existing 11 server and use the in-place upgrade as part of the install process.